# Can a angular component get data from ist outer/parent component

Tags: angular, components

I have made angular components and use them as elements in the HTML. Like:

```
<my-parent [setting]="A">
    <my-child-1>...</my-child-1>
    <my-child-2>...</my-child-2>
</my-parent>
<my-parent [setting]="B">
    <my-child-1>...</my-child-1>
    <my-child-2>...</my-child-2>
</my-parent>
```

So MyParent component  has an @Input() property that is given some settings.
But its children need to get this settings too. And I would rather not have to add [setting]="A" to all the children (as in real its not just one parameter).
Is there a way for the child components to get this property from its parent?
Note that there can be multiple parents, so if I use a service as communication platform, the children need to have some id of the parent to avoid getting data from the wrong parent. But I would rather not have to pass this id to all children.

Comment: You can make a service for child and parent if it becomes to complex so they can act as mediator. So your child ask the settings from services instead of your parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your children has always a parent, you can inject the parent in the constructor using [@Host](https://angular.io/api/core/Host)

```
   constructor(@Optional() @Host() private parent: ParentComponent){}
```

so you can use in any place

```
  //see that always check if parent is not null or undefined
  if (this.parent)
  {
      console.log(this.parent.setting)
  }
```

e.g. you can has a getter

```
   get settingParent()
   {
        //see that always check if parent is not null or undefined
        return this.parent?this.parent.setting:null;
   }
```